# What is the best way to load my own layer from database using leaflet?

Tags: ajax, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm using leaflet and osm, but i need to load my own layer on the map. I've added some function on map moveend event that uses ajax, loads layer and adds it on to the map. But when i move the map e.g. to right it first shows osm image without my layer, then when i stop moving it start to draw new layer. It looks stupid. How to fix it or what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried changing the event, for example dragend instead of moveend?

Comment: Can you post us a jsfiddle/demo of things in action?